# AFNetworking best practice to separate logic from view controllers and responsibilities to show data

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I use `AFNetworking` as a good library to work with Network. Usually I have some `API` class that handle all requests to server. `API` class is a singleton and includes some base url configuration, few blocks(closures) success and failure usually to pass data back to requested controller (object) and update UI/present new view controller and etc.

My question is this ok to handle alert error directly in API class. For example if we received some error form server do I need to process those errors directly in API class or I need to pass them back to controller and controller based on callback with error type will show needed alert with hardcoded information. Like "You've entered wrong email or password" and etc.

Also is this best practice handle errors from backend in success block or in failure block of `AFNetworking` for example when we `GET/POST/PUT/DELET` something.

As I know we have a lot of http code errors that we can process automatically like (status code 400 bad request and etc). But what if this is custom error what status code is better for this situation and I guess answer is - we should use `failure` callback for handling error from server. But what to clarify if this custom error.

Summarise

1. First question is about implementation of showing alerts to user based on error. Which class should we use for this (or it depends).
2. Second question is about success/failure block which one should handle custom error, or we need to `switch` error every time in failure block of `AFNeteworking`

Answer (score 0):

> First question is about implementation of showing alerts to user based
>   on error. Which class should we use for this (or it depends).

In this point it is quite a lot of options should be considerate. But i will share my experience. For solving of such kind of issues i am using own class for showing of the alerts in the application. This is done due to the high customization of the alert in one class.

Example :

```
CustomAlertController.alert("Test title", message: "message", acceptMessage: "OK") { () -> () in

}
```

Based on the patterns that you are using you could define where you should show alert. In my app i am using MVC. So my ViewController class should show alert dialog based on MVC rules.

Example

```
 MainViewController -> (Ask for data) NetworkController -> (Response with completion block) -> MainViewController -> (Show alert with response)
```

> Second question is about success/failure block which one should handle
>   custom error, or we need to switch error every time in failure block
>   of AFNeteworking

I like to investigate new frameworks (Moya) that are presented on [Github](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) so i found one that gives me vision about easy to use and manage framework that gives opportunity to handle network requests. So based on them it is possible to answer for you're question.

Small example from Moya:

```
provider.request(.Zen) { result in
    switch result {
    case let .Success(moyaResponse):
        // do something with the response data or statusCode
    case .Failure(error):
        // this means there was a network failure - either the request
        // wasn't sent (connectivity), or no response was received (server
        // timed out).  If the server responds with a 4xx or 5xx error, that
        // will be sent as a ".Success"-ful response.
    }
}
```

As it is possible to conclude usage of the switch case for handle of the request result it is quite good approach due to high readability of the code and simplicity.

Comment: thanks for answer, so as I understood if we have some failure response from server we should process it in failure method. I understood we need to use success only for success method and failure to process HTTP status codes and as I understood we need failure block for process custom error received from server. So actually if server sends me some response - "Your Alex account use has no statistic data on the data base", I guess there is no HTTP status code for it =) where should I process it in failure right? It's more backend question for sure.

Comment: Status code for this response will be probably 200. And yes it is more backend question. I has similar task and i was handling with help of the . Success case because request status was 200. And in success case i was checking if response contains custom errors that are presented as json filed.

Comment: yea, that what I asked, so what was my question, is the best way to put logic of handling custom errors to success or error block. Because then I can ask backend developer to generate success message instead of error and what actually the best practice was my initial question.

Comment: ok thanks for answer I will ask as well Matt to help here also, I've created question here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3491

Answer (score 0):

In Summarise Point 1:
In API class(AFHTTPSessionManager sub class) that handle all requests to server add below methods code.
API Call ---

```
- (void)getMyRecordsFromServer:(NSString *)url withLastModified:(NSTimeInterval)lastModified callbackHandler:(void (^)(id, NSError *))handler {

  self.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
  self.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];


  [self GET:url parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    handler(responseObject, nil);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    /**********************************************************************/
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey];
    NSInteger statusCode = response.statusCode;
    NSLog(@"Error Code=%ld",(long)statusCode);
    NSLog(@"Desc=%@",response.description);
    /**********************************************************************/
    [self baseFailureWithError:error onFailure:handler];

}];
```

}

Success call ----

```
 - (void)myGetRequestWithSuccess:(void (^)(id))success
              onFailure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure
 {
     [self GET:@"api/object"
           parameters:nil
           success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
           {
                 // success code here.
           } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
           {
            [[self class] baseFailureWithError:error onFailure:failure];
           }];
 }
```

after that implement generic logic in baseFailureWithError:: class method and then give call back to your view controller to implement user specific error validation.
Failure call ----

```
 - (void)baseFailureWithError:(NSError *)error
               onFailure:(void(^)(id responseObject,NSError *error))failure
 {
if (failure){
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = error.userInfo[@"AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey"];

    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]] && response.statusCode == 401){
        NSLog(@"Handle all 401's!");
        // decide show alert or not for point 2
    } else {
        failure(nil, error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! yea I understood, but what if I have 20 custom request which return custom error with custom message, do I need to overload baseFailureWithError with a lot of if blocks?

Comment: For common error message you can show it in one more if block. but your custom error message specific to API can be handled from callback.

Comment: I have made my answer more descriptive by adding API call. method params can be changed based on requirement.

Comment: How are you handling AFHTTPSessionManager subclasses are these singeltons? In case no, are you somehow handling deallocation of that subclass?